# Unable to get work Typescript typings for 'webextension-polyfill' library

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Currently, I'm trying to migrate existing google chrome extension to Typescript.
It uses 'webextension-polyfill' library in background script, but there are no definitions in npm for this library.

I have the following '**webextension-polyfill.d.ts**' file

```
interface Window {
    browser: typeof browser;
}

declare namespace browser.tabs {
    export function create(createProperties: chrome.tabs.CreateProperties): Promise<void>
    export function query(queryInfo: chrome.tabs.QueryInfo): Promise<chrome.tabs.Tab[]>
}

declare namespace browser.windows {
    export function getAll(getInfo: chrome.windows.GetInfo): Promise<chrome.windows.Window[]>
    export function create(window?: chrome.windows.CreateData): Promise<void>
}
```

My import looks like:

```
import 'webextension-polyfill';
```

And code which use library looks like:

```
function createTab(url: string) {
    browser.tabs.create({url: url}).then(...)
}
```

It compiles successfully, but I get runtime error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tabs' of undefined

In DevTools I can see that browser is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @Makyen I don't think this is relevant...

Comment: @akaSybe the error you are describing is actually not coming from Typescript- this is the browser tell you that the value of `browser` is not defined.

Comment: @DerekBrown, We haven't been given enough code to duplicate the error. Thus, my comment is accurate. As I stated, debugging questions *require* that a [mcve] which duplicates the problem be included in the question. For Chrome extensions, this *almost always* requires a *manifest.json*, because that defines in what context each portion of the code is running, which is *very* relevant for this error, as it is for most issues. We either need enough of the code/config to duplicate, and/or we need to see what is created and actually loaded by the browser.

Comment: @DerekBrown error occurs because of wrong definition file for 'webextension-polyfill', I can't figure out how to right export required namespaces and functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

That is the working example of module defintion:

**webextension-polyfill.d.ts**

```
declare namespace browser.tabs {
    export function create(tabInfo: chrome.tabs.CreateProperties): Promise<void>
    export function query(queryInfo: chrome.tabs.QueryInfo): Promise<chrome.tabs.Tab[]>
}

declare namespace browser.windows {
    export function create(createInfo: chrome.windows.CreateData): Promise<void>
    export function getAll(getInfo: chrome.windows.GetInfo): Promise<chrome.windows.Window[]>
}

declare module 'webextension-polyfill' {
    export = browser;
}
```

and now I can import '**webextension-polyfill**' library:

```
import * as browser from 'webextension-polyfill';
```

It works

Comment: Thanks for the tip, you unblocked me :) Also I just tried this, and it worked: `import * as browser from 'webextension-polyfill-ts';` so something may have changed (maybe got easier). In any case, your type declarations above are helpful.